# How to connect Apps Script to a Google Form submit button?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I have a simple Google-form for registration users on my service and they need to enter time when they will come. Its a problem when they can enter the same time that another user had placed and I need to check it when user push the submit button.
How can I do it with Apps Script? I have found few examples but still dont understand how to connect my script with submitting.

Comment: Is your Question 'How can I check what information the user is about to submit in Google forms before they submit it?' if so -> You can't do this, even with script, the script will only be able to pull the data on submission.

Comment: And what about triggers? I saw that I can use some triggers like "onSubmit" but dont know is it the same thing for my problem.

Comment: I've added a response to your question which covers this now that I'm sure what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to use Apps script to check data entered into a form pre-submission (Even with triggers, which are all dependent on the data being submitted). In order to do something similar using Apps script, you would need to use the [HTML service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/) to write a custom form with a function that allows you to check what data is submitted, and return an error message/refuse to accept the date if it clashes with a pre-existing date.

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to do something similar as the choice Eliminator Forms add-on.

Search the documentation for on form submit trigger. And it will give you an example.

But the catch 22 of it, is that your script runs after the form is submitted, so there is no way to stop the submission if it fails your check.